# Cannot render HTML document inside a Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am trying to render an HTML document inside Flexdashbaord using shiny. I am using some code to produce an HTML file from the inputs processed given by the user.

Data: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/04lzrzlqgmrt1pn/map1.csv?dl=0)

Below is the code:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: 
      version: 3
      bootswatch: yeti
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(gt)
library(htmltools)
library(viridis)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)


Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r echo=FALSE}

    selectInput("select_year", 
            label = "Year", 
            choices = c("2012", "2013", "2014")) 
    hr()
    
    selectInput("select_code", 
            label = "Course", 
            choices = c("i12", "i13", "i14"))
    
    hr()
    
    
    selectInput("select_title", 
            label = "Select a Discussion", 
            choices = c("Discussion on..", 
                        "Twitter trolls…", 
                        "NBA…"))
    
    hr()
    
    
    actionButton("update", "List Discussions", 
                 icon("refresh"),
                 class = "btn btn-primary")
    
Row
----------------------------------------------------------

reactive({
  htmltools::includeHTML(
  input$update,
  map1 %>%
    filter(Year == isolate(input$select_year)) %>% 
    filter(course_code == isolate(input$select_code)) %>% 
    filter(Title == isolate(input$select_title)) %>% 
    filter(text %in% sample(unique(text))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(review = get_sentences(comments)) %$%
    sentiment_by(review, text) %>%
    highlight("highlights.html")
)
})```
````

I cannot find a way to render it inside the dashboard

[image]

How can I access this HTML file generated from the code to display on my flexdashboard?

Comment: try wrapping inside `reactive`

Comment: Tried with `reactive()` but still cannot render as shown in the update.

Comment: Try just `HTML()` rather than `includeHTML()` The error you're getting is saying that what ever you're passing to `includeHTML()` is not being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The includeHTML function has path as parameter. You have to render first the html and then call it. Bu If you use "runtime: shiny" you can't use the generated html.